# Installing AWS SAM CLI on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 (M1)

Tags: macos, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to install `aws-sam-cli` on my M1 iMac. It already has Python 3 and AWS CLI, CDK et al configured. However, when I try the brew route it tell me to try the alternative install given the new chip. Tried that and I go through the install but when I enter `sam --version` to check the install in the opt location or the `~` it given me SAM version 1.17.

So I tried the pip method but I can see that the new version is already installed deep in opt. `aws-sam-cli in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.48.0)`. How do I get my `~` to pick up this when I enter `sam..` on the Terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` and see if the Python is before or after the `/usr/local/Cellar/`. You can try setting `PATH` variable to have the Python at the beginning (this may have unintended consequences). Alternatively, uninstall the Brew one. Or use Python `virtualenv` that does the PATH modification is a much safer way.

Comment: I did the brew method and when I switch to /opt/homebrew/ the `sam --version` gives me 1.48 but the version of my `~` is still 1.17. How would I modify my path to be able to access the latest SAM CLI without it impacting anything else

Comment: If you know where the `sam` is at in the `~` dir, just add the folder path to the beginning of the system PATH. `export PATH="/home/sandeep/sam/:$PATH"` for example. I'd recommend that you uninstall both of the `sam` applications and install the one that you need as a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023-09, AWS is no longer maintaining the AWS managed Home brew installed which was under (aws/tap/aws-sam-cli).
They recommend using the community managed installer.

The following command worked for me:

```
brew install aws-sam-cli
```